Adjusting list view height to grid in WPF
I have a grid, and inside this grid, there is a border. Inside the border, there is a ListView. My issue is that the ListView doesn't activate vertical scrolling according to the border's height. Instead, it increases the height of the ListView border, which causes the page to overflow.
Border:
<Border
    Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2"
    Background="#50505050"
    CornerRadius="8"
    Margin="0,0,10,0"
    Padding="10">
    <ui:ListView
        d:ItemsSource="{Binding BasicListViewItems, Mode=TwoWay}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding BasicListViewItems, Mode=TwoWay}"
        SelectedIndex="1"
        SelectionMode="Single">
        <ui:ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type models:Person}">
                <Grid Margin="8,0">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Ellipse
                        x:Name="Ellipse"
                        Grid.RowSpan="2"
                        Width="32"
                        Height="32"
                        Margin="6"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        Fill="{ui:ThemeResource ControlStrongStrokeColorDefaultBrush}" />
                    <TextBlock
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Margin="12,6,0,0"
                        FontWeight="Bold"
                        Text="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay}" />
                    <TextBlock
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Margin="12,0,0,6"
                        Foreground="{ui:ThemeResource TextFillColorSecondaryBrush}"
                        Text="{Binding Company, Mode=OneWay}" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ui:ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ui:ListView>
</Border>

Container grid:
<Grid Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,10,0,20">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="269*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="131*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

It looks like this
what I want it to be
it moves off the page
I tried to give listView the following property, but it didn't work:
MaxHeight="{Binding ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Border}}"


Does it happen with standard ListView?

There is no difference between them, I tried with normal listview and the same result

Probably you fail to give the ListView concrete height. It depends on how you lay out them in the Window.

Perhaps the most universal yet easy-to-maintan approach is this:
Make your top-level visible UI element a Grid, it should be arranged by rows. Define <Grid.RowDefinitions> for it. All rows should have Height="Auto" except one, that one needs to have Height="*".
Your variable-height element should be placed in this * row. This way, it will occupy all the remaining vertical space. This space will be controlled by the size of your entire window.
You can have more than one row with Height="*", but then you should better place a <GridSplitter< between other UI elements to be vertically resized, such as borders. The approach can be easily generalized for the combination of rows and columns at different levels of nesting, and some of them can also be of variable height or width.
This is a simple working XAML sample, tested:
<Window x:Class="My.Namespace.SampleWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"        
    Title="SampleWindow" Height="450" Width="800"
    ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip">
<Window.Resources>
    <Thickness x:Key="Padding">4</Thickness>
    <Style x:Key="Border" TargetType="Border">
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="3"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Border Padding="{StaticResource Padding}">
        <TextBlock>Top</TextBlock>
    </Border>
    <Border Grid.Row="1" BorderBrush="Navy" BorderThickness="3" Style="{StaticResource Border}" Margin="3">
        <ListView BorderThickness="0">
            <ListViewItem>1</ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem>2</ListViewItem>
            <!-- many items -->
            <ListViewItem>10000</ListViewItem>
        </ListView>
    </Border>
    <StatusBar Grid.Row="2" Padding="{StaticResource Padding}">
        <StatusBarItem>Bottom</StatusBarItem>
    </StatusBar>
</Grid>

Please try out and let us know if you face any problems with that.
